# Thoughts on custom pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I get a list of items that I'm supposed to present on a page. All I'm getting is the total amount of items and when I get the items the result is based on how many I want and what page I want, so if I have a page size of 10 and I want page 3 I use GetItems(3, 10) to get item 20-30 in the list. The results are presented in a simple table.

Now I want to add a pager tool and this is where I got stuck. They're in a form so I suppose I could use the onclick="this.form.submit(); to submit and get the new set of data but how can I make a simple a-link submit the form? It's just not working the way I expected it to.

This is the class I've made so far:

```
public class CustomPager
{
    int PageCount { get; set; }

    public CustomPager(int pageCount)
    {
        PageCount = pageCount;
    }

    public string CreateHTML()
    {
        string htmlMarkup = "";
        string linkMarkup = "<a id=\"page\" name=\"page\" onclick=\"this.form.submit();\">{0}</a>";

        for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
        {
            htmlMarkup += string.Format(linkMarkup, i.ToString());
        }

        return htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a 3rd party html helper instead?

When I started developing MVC I build my own pager just like you.

For my previous couple of projects I have been using this 3rd party html helper with all the build in functionality needed for paging.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/

Comment: I did but the ones I looked at seemed like to much work to implement. Didn't look at the one you just suggested though, so I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I found it very easy to implement. The documentation can be found here: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

Comment: Is it possible to only load one page at a time from the database? Feels like I need to load the entire set for every page.

Comment: As default it retrieves the entire dataset from the database. However it might be possible to change this but I haven't tried it myself.